# Finding the value of $k$ for an Uniform Distribution defined on $(-k,k)$

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution, integral, absolute-value

> If $X$ be an uniform distribution defined on $(-k,k)$, then the value of $k$ for so that :
> $$P(|X|<1) = P(|X|>2)$$

I began by defining the $p.d.f$ of the Uniform function namely:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2k}$$

Then we can re-write the **LHS** of the probability as :
$$ P(|X|<1) = P(-1<X<1)$$

And the **RHS** :
$$ P(|X|>2) = 1-P(|X|<2) \ = 1-P(-2<X<2) $$

Now solving the probability by $integration$ we get:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{2k} dx \ = 1  -  \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{2k}dx$$

$$\frac{1}{k} = 1  -   \frac{2}{k}$$
And therefore
$$k=3$$

Is my method and answer correct?

Comment: To me it seems correct

Comment: What you need is a method to check your work.  Probability problems are often susceptible to quick, easy, informative verification by simulation.  For instance, this `R` command prints estimates of the two probabilities based on a million draws of $X$: `(function(x) c(mean(abs(x) < 1), mean(abs(x) > 2))) (runif(1e6, -3, 3))`.  It runs in a fraction of a second and will tell you whether you're even close to correct.

Comment: Another approach to checking your work (besides the highly useful approach of simulation) would be to draw a picture. However, you can also simplify things by working directly with $V=|X|$ rather than with $X$ itself while doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your result is correct, but the method has a small flaw.
Your density should be
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2k} \cdot I_{(-k,k)} (x)
$$
This didn't change anything, since both your integration areas lie in $(-3,3)$, but in general this could fail.

Comment: What is the $I_{-k,k}$ that you have included in the density? And how would it effect the method if the integration were to lie between say (0,k)?

Comment: Kalvin, please search our site for [indicator function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=indicator+function).

Comment: @Kalvin The function $I_{(-k,k)}(x)$ is the indicator function which is $1$ if $x \in (-k,k)$ and $0$ otherwise.